# Unable to add data "innerHTML" to <div> tags using getElementByID()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I'm very new to HTML< Javascript concepts. So kindly go easy on me. 
I created 2  tags & want to selectively add data to each div tag using their ID, onload, but the the below code isn't adding "H1" & "h2" to each div tag.
Did i miss something ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titlehere</title>
    <p> Hello></p>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="tab1" onload="populatehtmlTab1()">
        <p>i1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" onload="populatehtmlTab2()">
        <p>i2</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function populatehtmlTab1() {
            document.getElementById(tab1).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tab1).innerHTML + "<p>h1</p>";
        }

        function populatehtmlTab2() {
            document.getElementById(tab2).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tab1).innerHTML + "<p>h2</p>";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementById(tab1)` => `getElementById('tab1')` selector must be a string

Comment: @MysterX: It's not a selector, it's an ID. But yes, that's the problem. Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: You may be wondering why you didn't get an error. The reason is that when you give elements `id` values, the browser creates *automatic globals* for them, so `tab1` isn't an unknown identifier, it's a global that refers to the element instance. If you pass that element instance into `getElementById`, it gets converted to string, and then that string is used as the ID to find. And doesn't get found. :-) (So why not use the automatic globals? Too many conflicts in the global scope of browsers. Best to retrieve them on purpose with `getElementById`.)

Comment: You can simplify it: `document.getElementById('tab2').innerHTML += "<p>h2</p>";`

Comment: Parameterise the `tab1` and `tab2`

Comment: @OmSao: "Parameterize" isn't the right word there. If you mean "put them in quotes," there isn't really a shorter way to say it than "put them in quotes." :-)

Comment: And finally: Don't append elements by converting the parent's contents to a string, and then reparsing that string. It's inefficient and wipes out event handlers. Use `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Comment: @MysterX: Adding single quotes 'tab1' is also not working. I don't see h1 & h2 displayed in html when i open in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this. Here is the code amended:

```js
function populatehtmlTab1() {
   document.getElementById('tab1').innerHTML =  "<p>h1</p>";
 }

 function populatehtmlTab2() {
   document.getElementById('tab2').innerHTML =  "<p>h2</p>";
 }

function loadHtml(){
  populatehtmlTab1();
  populatehtmlTab2();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titlehere</title>
    <p> Hello></p>

</head>
<body onload="loadHtml()">
    <div id="tab1" >
        <p>i1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2">
        <p>i2</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

First the element id selector must be a string:

```
document.getElementById('tab1')
```

second you just need to assign the innerHTML directly:

```
document.getElementById('tab2').innerHTML =  "<p>h2</p>";
```

Third you should use `onload` on the body, I wrapped both your functions into another function in my amended code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titlehere</title>
    <p> Hello></p>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="tab1" onload="populatehtmlTab1()">
        <p>i1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" onload="populatehtmlTab2()">
        <p>i2</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function populatehtmlTab1() {
            document.getElementById(tab1).innerHTML = $('#tab1').val() + "<p>h1</p>";
        }

        function populatehtmlTab2() {
            document.getElementById(tab2).innerHTML = $('#tab1').val() + "<p>h2</p>";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't mix javascript with jquery

Comment: function populatehtmlTab1() {
            document.getElementById(tab1).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tab1).value + "<p>h1</p>";
        }

        function populatehtmlTab2() {
            document.getElementById(tab2).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tab1).value + "<p>h2</p>";
        }

Answer (score 1):

- `div` elements do not have `onload` so your functions are not being called.
- Use `insertAdjacentHTML` for the insertion
- Pass a string to `getElementById`.

```js
function populatehtmlTab1() {
  document.getElementById("tab1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>h1</p>");
}

function populatehtmlTab2() {
  document.getElementById("tab2").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>h2</p>");
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  populatehtmlTab1();
  populatehtmlTab2();
});
```

```html
<div id="tab1" onload="populatehtmlTab1()">
  <p>i1</p>
</div>

<div id="tab2" onload="populatehtmlTab2()">
  <p>i2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is insertAdjacentHTML() a replacement for innerHTML ? What is "beforeend" string here in 1st argument ? And is addEventListener() a replacement toonload() ?

Comment: @codeLover: In many cases, yes. It adds new content from the HTML you provide *without* first destroying and recreating the existing DOM. The way you were doing it, it had to take the current elements, generate HTML from them, add that HTML to the new HTML, destroy the old elements, and finally create new elements from the new, larger HTML string. That's too much work, and it can cause bugs in some cases. Using `+=` has the same problem.

Comment: The `"beforeend"` is one of four positional arguments. They are relative to the element it's called on. The args are `"beforebegin"`, `"afterbegin"`, `"beforeend"`, and `"afterend"`. These are relative to the opening or closing tag, so they insert before, inside at first position, inside at last position, or after the element.

Comment: `addEventListener` is a modern method for binding event handlers, and the `DOMContentLoaded` event is called when the `document` has loaded but before other content like images is loaded. If you need to wait for images too, then use `"load"` instead of `"DOMContentLoaded"`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for mixing jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titlehere</title>
    <p> Hello></p>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="tab1" onload="populatehtmlTab1()">
        <p>i1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" onload="populatehtmlTab2()">
        <p>i2</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function populatehtmlTab1() {
            document.getElementById(tab1).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tab1).value + "<p>h1</p>";
        }

        function populatehtmlTab2() {
            document.getElementById(tab2).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tab1).value + "<p>h2</p>";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If the element 'value' is not detected in 'innerHTML', you can generate variables:

```
var tab1Value = document.getElementById(tab1).value;
```